# How do I change the background image of 1 HTML window from another HTML window?

Tags: javascript, html

As the title of this question sez :

How do I change the background image of 1 HTML window from another HTML window ?

I have 9 HTML windows.

Call them ‘HTMLWindow_0’ & HTMLWindow_1’ through ‘HTMLWindow_8’.

HTML Window1 has a background image and a set of 8 buttons.

Each button opens up a new HTML window with a different background image.

Call them ‘HMTLWindow_1’ though  ‘HTMLWindow_8’.

In other words, Button–n on ‘HTMLWindow_0’ creates ‘HTMLWindow_n’.

Each of the HTML windows created by the set of buttons on ‘HTMLWindow_0’ has a background image associated with it.

Background image x is associated with HTMLWindow_x.

The HTML & Javascript for ‘HTMLWindow_0’ is in a file called ‘HTMLWindow_0.html’.

The HTML for ‘HTMLWindow_1’ through ‘HTMLWindow_8’ is in a file called ‘HTMLWindow_x.html’.

The set of file pathnames for the images used as backgrounds for the HTML windows 1 though 8 are stored in a Javascript array called ‘Image_Array’ in the file ‘HTMLWindow_0.html’.

The HTML that acts upon button clicks in HTMLWindow_0 is as follows :

```
<div class="toc_button_01"><button onClick="changePage ('Toc 01',  2)"> </button></div>
 <div class="toc_button_02"><button onClick="changePage ('Toc 02',  4)"> </button></div>
<div class="toc_button_03"><button onClick="changePage ('Toc 03',  5)"> </button></div>
<div class="toc_button_04"><button onClick="changePage ('Toc 04',  6)"> </button></div>
<div class="toc_button_05"><button onClick="changePage ('Toc 05',  7)"> </button></div>
<div class="toc_button_06"><button onClick="changePage ('Toc 06',  8)"> </button></div>
<div class="toc_button_07"><button onClick="changePage ('Toc 07',  9)"> </button></div>
 <div class="toc_button_08"><button onClick="changePage ('Toc 08', 10)"> </button></div>
```

In other words,  clicking on any of the 8 buttons activates a JavaScript function called ‘changepage’.

‘changepage’ looks like this :

```
function changePage (buttonName,
            buttonNumber)
{
    alert (   "We're in the 'changePage' function !" 
            + "\n"
            + "We just clicked on the "
            +  buttonName
            + " button !"
            + "\n"
            + "Button Number  = "
            +  buttonNumber
            + "\n"
            + "Current Page URL = "
            +  Image_Array [buttonNumber]); 

document.getElementById("image1").src = Image_Array [buttonNumber];
    generatePageContent (buttonNumber);

} // End of function changePage ()
```

‘changepage’ in turns calls another JavaScript function called ‘    generatePageContent’.

‘generatePageContent’ is the actual JavaScript function that creates the new HTML windows 1 through 8 depending on which button was pushed on ‘HTMLWindow_0’.

‘generatePageContent’ looks like this :

```
function generatePageContent (buttonNumber)
{
    alert (   "We're in the 'generatePageContent' function !"
            + "\n"
            + "Button Number  = "
            +  buttonNumber
            + "\n"
            + "Current Page URL = "
            +  Image_Array [buttonNumber]); 

    var newWindow = window.open (' HTMLWindow_x.html ',
'',
'width = 788, height = 632, left = 100, top = 200, toolbar = yes');

    newWindow.document.getElementById("image2").src = Image_Array [buttonNumber];

} // End of function generatePageContent ()
```

I have no problem creating any of the new HTML windows 1 through 8.

In other words, the line :

```
var newWindow = window.open (' HTMLWindow_x.html ',
'',
'width = 788, height = 632, left = 100, top = 200, toolbar = yes');
```

in the Javascript function ‘generatePageContent’ will create any of the HTML windows 1 through 8 depending on which button 1 through 8 was clicked on ‘HTMLWindow_0’.

However the line :

```
newWindow.document.getElementById("image2").src = Image_Array [buttonNumber];
```

in the Javascript function ‘generatePageContent’ doesn’t work.

This is the line that is supposed to change the background image in the creatED HTML windows 1 through 8.

It is simply ignored.

The interesting thing is that I have no problem changing the background image in the calling HTML window ‘HTMLWindow_0’.

The line :

```
document.getElementById("image1").src = Image_Array [buttonNumber];
```

inside the Javascript function ‘changepage’ handles this fine.

So, I guess the actual question is :

Why does :

```
document.getElementById("image1").src = Image_Array [buttonNumber];
```

inside the Javascript function ‘changepage’ change the background image in  ‘HTMLWindow_0’ but

```
newWindow.document.getElementById("image2").src = Image_Array [buttonNumber];
```

inside the Javascript function ‘generatePageContent’ doesn’t change the background image in any of ‘HTMLWindow_0’ through HTMLWindow_8’ ?

The ‘image1’ reference inside the JavaScript function ‘changePage’ refers to the following HTML code inside file HTMLWindow_0 :

```
     <div class="img1">
         <img   id      = "image1"
                src     = "../BookListPages/ClearingThePath/CTP-02.tiff" 
                alt     = "Clearing The Path ..." 
                width   = "765" 
                height  = "580" 
                border  = "2" 
         /> <!-- End of img tag. -->
    </div>
```

The ‘image2’ reference inside the JavaScript function ‘generatePageContent’ refers to the following HTML code inside file HTMLWindow_x :

```
     <div class="img">
         <img   id      = "image2"
                src     = "../BookListPages/NoSuchPageForThisBook.tif" 
                alt     = "Clearing The Path ..." 
                width   = "765" 
                height  = "580" 
                border  = "2" 
         /> <!-- End of img tag. -->
```

In other words, and simply put, I’m trying to create an HTML window from inside another HTML window using a button inside the creatING window and I want to vary the background image of the creatED HTML  window depending on which button was clicked on in the creatING window.

What am I missing/screwing up here ?

I apologize for the complexity of this post but I wanted to make sure that I’ve clearly explained exactly what I’m trying to do and I’ve provided all the HTML and the Javascript source involved in supporting what it is I’m trying to do here.

Finally, I’d like to thank everyone in advance for whatever advice, help, references and suggestions you can give me towards resolving this problem.

Comment: By window do you mean iframe? or if all the pages are in independent windows just have the background of each be in its own html. also so you have a very long question and its hard to read it all, try creating a sample of your page using [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and send us the link here so we can help you better :)

Comment: Is the path to the img correct? Is the html file loaded in HTMLWindow_0 relatively in the same folder as the other pages you load?  
window.open (' HTMLWindow_x.html ', ....) --> The spaces feel strange :)  
Maybe it is because the popup window gains focus?  
What happens when you click a second time on the same button?

Comment: I think you might want to have a look at the comment of Sarnold.. It seems the things you have been trying to send me were rejected.. Can you briefly send me a comment what you want to ask me?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I started. This worked.

```
var newWindow = window.open('HTMLWindow_x.html', '', 'width = 788, height = 632, left = 100, top = 200, toolbar = yes');
setTimeout(function() { 
    window.focus();
    newWindow.document.getElementById("image2").src = Image_Array [buttonNumber];
}
, 2000); // I tend to use extreme values when bumping into issues like these.. just to see
```

Using the setTimeout kinda showed me it was a 'timing' issue. This made me think that maybe the opened window wasn't loaded yet.. The next step in your debugging process could make you realize that you should be using newWindow.onload..
Here's a complete working sample:

**html1.html**

```
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <div class="img">
                 <img id="image2" src= "0.png" alt= "Clearing The Path ..." width="765" height="580" border="2" />
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**html0.html**

```
<html>
        <head>
            <script>
function changePage(buttonName,
                buttonNumber)

{
    document.getElementById("image1").src = Image_Array [buttonNumber];
    generatePageContent (buttonNumber);

}
function generatePageContent (buttonNumber)
{
    try {
        var newWindow = window.open (' html1.html ', 'someWindowName', 'width = 788, height = 632, left = 100, top = 200, toolbar = yes');
        newWindow.onload = loadSecondWindow.apply(this, [buttonNumber, newWindow]);
    } 
    catch(e)
    {
        // although IE throws a 'not implemented' exception here, it changes the image..
        // does anyone know why?
    }
}

function loadSecondWindow(buttonNumber, newWindow)
{
    setTimeout(function() { 
        //window.focus();
        newWindow.document.getElementById("image2").src = Image_Array [buttonNumber];           
    }, 500); // I started with a timeout of 2000 
}

var Image_Array = {};
Image_Array['0'] = '0.png';
Image_Array['1'] = '1.png';

function curry() {
    if (!arguments.length) return this;
    var __method = this, args = slice.call(arguments, 0);
    return function() {
      var a = merge(args, arguments);
      return __method.apply(this, a);
    }
  }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="toc_button_01">
        <button onClick="changePage ('Toc 01',  1)"> open html1.html</button></div>
            <div class="img1">
                 <img   id      = "image1"
                        src     = "0.png" 
                        alt     = "Clearing The Path ..." 
                        width   = "765" 
                        height  = "580" 
                        border  = "2" 
                 /> <!-- End of img tag. -->
        </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you TweeZz … I just logged on and I haven't tried out your suggestion but I do sincerely appreciate your having taken the time to give me an answer that is very likely to work … thanks again … Simon

Comment: I don't like the setTimeout of 500ms. In IE it worked for me with a much smaller timeout, but not in FF. 
Anyone a suggestion to improve this?

Comment: Hi TweeZz :I apologize for not getting back to you earlier. Memorial Day and various pother things prevented me from testing out your solution. It worked ! Gawd Bless You TweeZz ! I really do appreciate all your help. I'm going to spend most of today picking apart your code to see how the various pieces work together. After that I'll integrate it into my own code. And … Once again TweeZz I really do appreciate your help … Simon

Comment: Hehe no problemo :) But if this helped you, why don't you mark it as 'answer'? :) Do let me know if you need some further assistance..

Comment: Hi TweeZz :

I’ve been trying to respond to your very helpful comments in the “Comment” section of this web page but it doesn’t seem to be accepting my comments.

I don’t know why … Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Actually yesterday I also tried to write a comment under this one, but somehow it thought I was writing a 2nd answer.. I didn't get it..

Comment: I hit "return" in the previous comment thinking it would take me to a new line … But on … It posted the comment. Dont' the people who designed the User Interface for this web site realize that it is intuitively natural to assume the the "Add Comment" butto next to the Comment Text Area would do this and that hitting the "Return" key should intuitively take you to a new line in the Comment Text Area ?

Comment: I just put another "Comment" in the "Comment" area and rather than posting it the site just wiped it out … I find that the User Interface of this web site is sometimes very counter intuitive and therefore difficult to work with …

Comment: Because I’m having so many problems posting in the “Comments” and “Answer” of this posting I’m going to create a new Question to clear up the remaining issues that I haven’t been able to solve using the extremely helpful solution code that TweeZz so kindly posted.

The new question is called :

“Why do I sometimes get 2 identical windows rather than 1 unique window when I try to create a callED HTML window from a callING HTML window ?”

Comment: @Simon: You keep posting that my answer is very helpful.. Why don't you mark it as answer then? :)